# No pylint warning "Redefining built-in" for a class local variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I came across a Django model like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    type = CharField()
    ...
```

However, `pylint` does not issue any warnings about redefining the built-in function `type`. It is only when I move it out of the class to the global scope `pylint` warns about this, but not within the class. Is this the expected behavior? If so, how can I override it to show warnings within classes or functions as well?

```
VSCode 1.61.0
Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.8.10
```

Comment: Removing django tag as it is not related to django. The behavior is the same with any class attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is a normal behaviour as you don't hide `type` here
since you need to write something like `my_car.type` to access the
`type` attribute so there is no risk.

If you still want pylint to warn you about that you can add `type`
to the list `bad-names` in your `pylintrc` file.  It will raise a `C0104: disallowed-name` message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would this example be a code smell, though?

Comment: I would say so.  In my opinion, this kind of naming convention should not depend on whether the variable is class attribute, a global variable, and so on. They should apply whatever the context.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, even you redefining the built-in functions such as `type` out of the class to the global scope, you still can access it through `builtins.type` in Py3 and `__builtin__.type` in Py2.